# changing manifest in netbeans (Trusted-Library=true attribute)

Tags: java, security, jar, applet

I need to tag JAR files with the Trusted-Library=true attribute...somehow. When I add Trusted-Library=true at the manifest, I get class not found exception. The manifest I see in Netbeans is,

```
 Manifest-Version: 1.0
 X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
```

When I use the webstart options from project properties and select Trusted-Library from signing part I get same class not found.

What can I do?

**EDIT: The manifest in the jar:**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Created-By: 1.6.0_45-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Name: JTwainLicense.class
SHA1-Digest: L4BTAOFRNEyeRA9Tw1Z3EQ0Ud5c=

Name: com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/TestApplet.class
SHA1-Digest: 8EetVUQhuvNH4urJB3oDG66vYas=

Name: com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/TestConstants.class
SHA1-Digest: ycjvP24IF/ggDBtj4v/r5Bz5nBY=

Name: com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/TestApplet_buttonScan_actionAdapter.class
SHA1-Digest: EWMDyf2p4ka8jOD8Fr2Fbrj/Tf0=

Name: META-INF/INDEX.LIST
SHA1-Digest: ymizlIYUM8SXgYNjYA30r1G0X7A=

Name: com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/ImageDisplayPanel.class
SHA1-Digest: Ae0oc23YVy8W9oTJoiRT2M1o4cY=
```

**The manifest with class not found error.**

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.3
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Trusted-library: true
Created-By: 1.6.0_45-b06 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)

Name: JTwainLicense.class
SHA1-Digest: L4BTAOFRNEyeRA9Tw1Z3EQ0Ud5c=

Name: com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/TestApplet.class
SHA1-Digest: 8EetVUQhuvNH4urJB3oDG66vYas=

Name: com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/TestConstants.class
SHA1-Digest: ycjvP24IF/ggDBtj4v/r5Bz5nBY=

Name: com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/TestApplet_buttonScan_actionAdapter.class
SHA1-Digest: EWMDyf2p4ka8jOD8Fr2Fbrj/Tf0=

Name: META-INF/INDEX.LIST
SHA1-Digest: ymizlIYUM8SXgYNjYA30r1G0X7A=

Name: com/asprise/util/jtwain/web/ImageDisplayPanel.class
SHA1-Digest: Ae0oc23YVy8W9oTJoiRT2M1o4cY=
```

Stacktrace:

```
ERROR: com/asprise/util/jtwain/SourceManager
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-3" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:            com/asprise/util/jtwain/SourceManager
at com.asprise.util.jtwain.web.TestApplet.buttonScan_actionPerformed(UploadApplet.java:388)
at com.asprise.util.jtwain.web.TestApplet_buttonScan_actionAdapter.actionPerformed(UploadApplet.java:548)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
....
```

Comment: *"The manifest I see in Netbeans is,"*  What is the manifest you see in the Jar?  Are there any other Jars required?

Comment: added manifests for both conditions

Comment: I added the stack trace: Beside that, when I open the console I can see weird things like: **basic:** _LD - All JAR files signed: file:/C:/Users/myC/Documents/NetBeansProjects/jtwain/JTwain3/dist/jnlpcomponent1.jnlp_
**basic:** _passing security checks; secureArgs:true, allSigned:false_   **security:** _Istrusted: file:/C:/Users/myC/Documents/NetBeansProjects/jtwain/JTwain3/dist/launch.jnlp false_  Everything is signed.

Comment: `launch.jnl‌​p`  I did not realize a JNLP was involved, please validate it in [JaNeLA](http://pscode.org/janela/) then post the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Trusted-Library: true makes the jar file load in a separate classloader that is the parent of the classloader that loads Applets/WebStart applications.

See: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2278127
and also see:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/mixed_code.html

That means your trusted code can not access un-trusted code except through Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().

You could also add Trusted-Library: true to all jars you depend on.